# A general error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, picturebox, flowlayoutpanel

OK so I know this issue is all over the web, but I don't think any of the solutions I've read suit my specific issue.

**Background**
I'm writing a small C# WinForm application in which users at our company can view, edit, and otherwise manipulate image files. The image details (file type, store location etc) are stored in a database, and when a user selects a given file from a DataGridView, page one of the image is displayed within the "main" PictureBox control, while thumbnail copies of all subsequent pages (if it's a multipage document) are shown nearby.

When opening an image, the program splits the document into multiple images, creates a new PictureBox control for each image and adds that PictureBox to the FlowLayoutPanel, and this is where the error is occurring.

I have tested the program with single and multipage images, and everything is fine except when I try to open an image containing lots of pages (180+). If the program has to open and image with less pages than that, everything is fine. However when I test images that are 200+ pages, I receive:

"An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+"

Regardless of how large the image is (190, 200, 300, 500 pages), the error *generally* occurs at around the page 185 mark (but it's not always page 185).

[image: A screenshot of the code causing the error. This is the backgroundworker that does all the work splitting the images]

I don't think the error is in relation to the image itself or the way they're being processed; all other images (i.e. ones with less pages) are fine. Perhaps there's a limit on the number/size etc of the picturebox controls I'm adding to the flowlayout panel?

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to watch the GDI heap. You can use the task manager for this.. One way to avoid this might be to choose a common size (<= 256x256px) for the preview images and stuff them into an ImageList; it can hold large numbers without using up GDI handles or space.

Comment: Btw, Instead of adding all those PictureBoxes, each of which is a control you would save resources by using a ListView, View=LargeIcon to display your thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated the code to use a ListView instead. So far, with the smaller images, it's certainly a better option than what I was doing previously.

HOWEVER, the issue with the exception is still occurring with images with lots of pages. To narrow things down, I took out all the code that related to displaying the images and just concentrated on the splitting of the pages.

It's something to do with the **Image tempImg = (Image)originalImage.Clone();**

If I do the same thing, but like **Image tempImg = originalImage;** then it's fine.

Comment: So...it's "working", but if I make a change to the image, it will affect the original copy, which I wanted to preserve.